# TransformXML in VBA removes Encoding

Tags: xml, vba, xslt

So having got much help of here, which im thoroughly thankful for!

I have worked out how to export and apply XSLT to the exporting file from MS Access,

But now when i transform the file throught this code:

```
Application.TransformXML "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDStest.xml", _
"C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDSTest.xsl", _
"C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDStest.xml"
WellFormedXMLOutput = True
```

The XML that it creates does not have the encoding specified in the XSLT??

Snippet of exported and transformed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DatabaseData>
<Customers>
<Idx>1</Idx>
<FirstName>David</FirstName>
```

The XSL Used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DatabaseData>
      <xsl:for-each select="dataroot/Customers">
        <Customers>
          <Idx>
            <xsl:value-of select="Idx"/>
          </Idx>
          <FirstName>
            <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
          </FirstName>
          <LastName>
            <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
          </LastName>
          <IconIdx>
            <xsl:value-of select="IconIdx"/>
          </IconIdx>
          <PhoneNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="PhoneNumber"/>
          </PhoneNumber>
          <Email>
            <xsl:value-of select="Email"/>
          </Email>
          <Street>
            <xsl:value-of select="Street"/>
          </Street>
          <City>
            <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
          </City>
          <State>
            <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
          </State>
          <ZipCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="ZipCode"/>
          </ZipCode>
          <Available>
            <xsl:value-of select="Available"/>
          </Available>
          <SPIndex>
            <xsl:value-of select="SPIndex"/>
          </SPIndex>
        </Customers>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </DatabaseData>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there any reason why MS Access would remove the encoding when transforming the XML file??

Comment: Does Access write the transformation result to a file? If not, with a string in memory, there is no encoding so it might make sense not to output an `encoding` pseudo attribute on the XML declaration.

Comment: Sorry im going to have to plead stupidty and ask where you mean the encoding pseudo?

Comment: It comes from exporting in VBA, the file is exported then transformed upon export in VBA..

Comment: The term "pseudo" attribute is just used to distinguish that `encoding` in the XML declaration from "real" attributes on element nodes. Sorry if that sounded confusing. As for the Access problem, I don't know much about its export and XSLT features, hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: SO completely bringing up an old subject....

But realised what i need..

Basically whenever i Transform the XML with the XSLT file..

The created XML removes the Encoding declaration.. have been trying to figure out a way of stopping it but keep coming up stumps...

SO it includes the XML Declaration as a processing instruction node.. But i also need it to include the Encoding Processing instruction aswell?

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the *Application.TransformXML* for the [transformNodeToObject method](http://www.know-access.com/view/35839-use-access-vba-to-import-xml-and-stylesheet-local-drive.html). I am finding the former is a little limited in handling xml transformations.

But you have to select the Microsoft XML reference either v3 or v6 under Tools of VBA editor. Possibly, you can also late bind.

Below is corresponding script to align to yours and uses 'Microsoft XML, v3' reference.

> ```
> Dim xmlfile As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
> Dim xslfile As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
> Dim newXMLDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
>
> xmlfile.async = False
> xmlfile.Load "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDStest.xml"
>
> xslfile.async = False
> xslfile.Load "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDSTest.xsl"
>
> xmlfile.transformNodeToObject xslfile, newXMLDoc
> newXMLDoc.Save "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\" & NEWXMLNAME & ".xml"
>
> Set xmlfile = Nothing
> Set xslfile = Nothing
> Set newXMLDoc = Nothing
> ```