# How to import attribute-centric XML to MS Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, import

I need help doing 2 things:

1-import the below attribute-centric XML to Microsoft Access (Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2303 Build 16.0.16227.20202) 64-bit ) into 4 different tables

2-import hundreds of these XMLs at once to Microsoft Access

In the XML, the "appointmentid" (<demographics appointmentid="0000000000000000" functioncode="" workstationname="") has to be associated with every record in all tables, as the primary key with duplicates allowed in some of the tables. Here are the tables with the headers listed for each table that I need from this XML:

Demographics:  appointmentid (no duplicates), BirthDate, CandidateAddress1, CandidateAddress2, CandidateAddress3, CandidateAddress4, CandidateCity, CandidateCountryCode, CandidateDayPhoneLong, CandidateEveningPhoneLong, CandidateFirstName, CandidateLastName, CandidateMiddleName, CandidatePostalCode, CandidateSSN, CandidateState, clientCandidateId2, ClientID, CompanyName, eligibilityid1, EmailAddress, Extension, Fax, governmentId, IssuingCountryId, LanguageId, MotherMaidenName

Scores:  appointmentid (duplicates ok), sitecode, programcode, examcode, name3, examformname, startdatetime, enddatetime, duration, restartcount, count, countcorrect, countincorrect, countskipped, countmarked, scorevalue, scorepercent, scoredisplay, passindicator, scoremin, scoremax, scorecut, scorecutpercent, scoringmethod, grade, count8, countcorrect9, countincorrect10, countskipped11, countmarked12, startdatetime13, enddatetime14, duration15, scorevalue16, scorepercent17, scoredisplay18, passindicator19, scoremin20, scoremax21, scorecut22, scorecutpercent23

Items:  appointmentid (duplicates ok), examcode, name24, sequence, scored, duration25, progid, weight, presented, visited, response, correctresponse, score, scoremin26, scoremax27, scorenom, complete, skipped, marked

Sections:  appointmentid (duplicates ok), examcode, name28, count29, countcorrect30, countincorrect31, countskipped32, countmarked33

I'm guessing I need an XSLT file to do this, but I can't figure out how to get one to work. I have copied numerous examples over the past week, tweaked them, but none of them work. I have also tried the directions at Microsoft that uses the Northwind.mdb to create an XSLT, but it gets stuck on the open command. It won't open the Northwind.mdb, and I've looked at all the trust settings but no joy.

Maybe there's a better way? I've already figured out how to mass import the XMLs via Excel Power Query, and I've written a macro to make the tables I need in separate Excel sheets. But this can take hours to do and is painfully slow and far from perfect. Also, it results in decentralized data in various Excel files which makes analysis over time difficult. I've successfully created simple Access databases for similar data (.dat/.txt files) and used Power BI to make reports, which is my goal with these attribute-centric XMLs.

Your help and expertise is greatly, GREATLY, appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<simpleXMLResult version="1.4" xmlns="http://sdk.prometric.com/schemas/SimpleXMLResults1_4">
<demographics appointmentid="000000000000000000" functioncode="" workstationname="">
<demographic name="BirthDate" value="" />
<demographic name="CandidateAddress1" value="123 Anywhere Dr" />
<demographic name="CandidateAddress2" value="NONE GIVEN" />
<demographic name="CandidateAddress3" value="" />
<demographic name="CandidateAddress4" value="" />
<demographic name="CandidateCity" value="Nowhere" />
<demographic name="CandidateCountryCode" value="USA" />
<demographic name="CandidateDayPhoneLong" value="" />
<demographic name="CandidateEveningPhoneLong" value="5555555555" />
<demographic name="CandidateFirstName" value="Firstname" />
<demographic name="CandidateLastName" value="Lastname" />
<demographic name="CandidateMiddleName" value="" />
<demographic name="CandidatePostalCode" value="11111" />
<demographic name="CandidateSSN" value="" />
<demographic name="CandidateState" value="XX" />
<demographic name="clientCandidateId2" value="" />
<demographic name="ClientID" value="999999" />
<demographic name="CompanyName" value="" />
<demographic name="eligibilityid1" value="G88888888" />
<demographic name="EmailAddress" value="email@email.com" />
<demographic name="Extension" value="" />
<demographic name="Fax" value="" />
<demographic name="governmentId" value="" />
<demographic name="IssuingCountryId" value="" />
<demographic name="LanguageId" value="" />
<demographic name="MotherMaidenName" value="" />
</demographics>
<delivery workstationname="" sitecode="0000" driverversion="" />
<exam programcode="PCODE" examcode="EXAM" resourcefilename="" resourceversion="" name="Exam Name Here" examformname="Exam Form 4444.a" driverversion="" startdatetime="2021-02-30T12:41:02.177" enddatetime="2021-02-30T15:08:00" duration="7997764" restartcount="0" count="150" countcorrect="104" countincorrect="46" countskipped="0" countmarked="0" functioncode="" workstationname="">
<score scorevalue="495" scorepercent="69.333" scoredisplay="495" passindicator="f" scoremin="200" scoremax="800" scorecut="500" scorecutpercent="70" scalescore="495" scoringmethod="Scale" grade="Fail" />
<sections>
<section name="1" count="75" countcorrect="48" countincorrect="27" countskipped="0" countmarked="0" startdatetime="2021-02-30T12:41:02.177" enddatetime="2021-02-30T15:08:00" duration="4000654">
<score scorevalue="48" scorepercent="64" scoredisplay="48" passindicator="p" scoremin="0" scoremax="75" scorecut="0" />
<itemgroup name="BLAH01" sequence="1" scored="0" duration="29748" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="D" correctresponse="B" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH02" sequence="2" scored="1" duration="70847" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="A" correctresponse="C" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH03" sequence="3" scored="1" duration="8883" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="B" correctresponse="D" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH04" sequence="4" scored="0" duration="11775" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="A" correctresponse="A" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH05" sequence="5" scored="1" duration="72956" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="A" correctresponse="B" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH06" sequence="6" scored="1" duration="57026" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="B" correctresponse="D" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH07" sequence="7" scored="0" duration="25106" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="D" correctresponse="D" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH08" sequence="8" scored="1" duration="58834" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="C" correctresponse="D" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH09" sequence="9" scored="1" duration="37991" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="D" correctresponse="C" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH10" sequence="10" scored="1" duration="26199" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="C" correctresponse="C" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
</section>
<section name="Break" count="0" countcorrect="0" countincorrect="0" countskipped="0" countmarked="0" startdatetime="2022-04-30T12:41:02.177" enddatetime="2022-04-30T15:08:00" duration="10817" />
<section name="2" count="75" countcorrect="56" countincorrect="19" countskipped="0" countmarked="0" startdatetime="2022-04-30T12:41:02.177" enddatetime="2022-04-30T15:08:00" duration="3957547">
<score scorevalue="56" scorepercent="74.667" scoredisplay="56" passindicator="p" scoremin="0" scoremax="75" scorecut="0" />
<itemgroup name="BLAH91" sequence="1" scored="1" duration="62694" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="B" correctresponse="A" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH92" sequence="2" scored="1" duration="57879" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="B" correctresponse="D" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH93" sequence="3" scored="1" duration="33024" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="C" correctresponse="C" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH94" sequence="4" scored="1" duration="34385" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="B" correctresponse="B" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH95" sequence="5" scored="1" duration="39753" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="D" correctresponse="A" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH96" sequence="6" scored="1" duration="12777" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="A" correctresponse="A" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH97" sequence="7" scored="1" duration="37405" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="A" correctresponse="B" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH98" sequence="8" scored="0" duration="37408" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="D" correctresponse="D" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH99" sequence="9" scored="0" duration="88957" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="B" correctresponse="B" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="BLAH100" sequence="10" scored="1" duration="31457" progid="MultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="D" correctresponse="D" score="1" scoremin="0" scoremax="1" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
</section>
<section name="S" count="0" countcorrect="0" countincorrect="0" countskipped="0" countmarked="0" startdatetime="2022-04-30T12:41:02.177" enddatetime="2022-04-30T15:08:00" duration="28746">
<itemgroup name="Survey1 2021" sequence="1" scored="0" duration="4093" progid="SurveyMultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="A" correctresponse="" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="0" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="Survey2 2021" sequence="2" scored="0" duration="6244" progid="SurveyMultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="A" correctresponse="" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="0" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="Survey3 2021" sequence="3" scored="0" duration="4380" progid="SurveyMultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="B" correctresponse="" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="0" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="Survey4 2021" sequence="4" scored="0" duration="3070" progid="SurveyMultipleChoice" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="C" correctresponse="" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="0" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup name="Survey5 2021" sequence="5" scored="0" duration="10959" progid="SurveyEssay" weight="1" presented="1" visited="1">
<item response="no" correctresponse="" score="0" scoremin="0" scoremax="0" scorenom="0" complete="1" skipped="0" marked="0" />
</itemgroup>
</section>
</sections>
<categories>
<category name="FLY FISHING" count="22" countcorrect="17" countincorrect="5" countskipped="0" countmarked="0">
<itemref name="BLAH1" />
<itemref name="BLAH05" />
<itemref name="BLAH10" />
<itemref name="BLAH93" />
<itemref name="BLAH94" />
</category>
<category name="CANOEING" count="23" countcorrect="17" countincorrect="6" countskipped="0" countmarked="0">
<itemref name="BLAH02" />
<itemref name="BLAH09" />
<itemref name="BLAH92" />
<itemref name="BLAH96" />
</category>
<category name="WATER SKIING" count="23" countcorrect="13" countincorrect="10" countskipped="0" countmarked="0">
<itemref name="BLAH03" />
</category>
<category name="RAFTING" count="15" countcorrect="10" countincorrect="5" countskipped="0" countmarked="0">
<itemref name="BLAH04" />
<itemref name="BLAH06" />
<itemref name="BLAH97" />
<itemref name="BLAH98" />
<itemref name="BLAH99" />
</category>
<category name="TUBING" count="22" countcorrect="18" countincorrect="4" countskipped="0" countmarked="0">
<itemref name="BLAH07" />
</category>
<category name="PARASAILING" count="15" countcorrect="11" countincorrect="4" countskipped="0" countmarked="0">
<itemref name="BLAH08" />
<itemref name="BLAH95" />
</category>
<category name="JETSKIING" count="30" countcorrect="18" countincorrect="12" countskipped="0" countmarked="0">
<itemref name="BLAH91" />
<itemref name="BLAH100" />
</category>
</categories>
<customattributes>
<customattribute name="EventAcronym" value="PCODE" />
<customattribute name="TestCode" value="FORMCODE" />
</customattributes>
</exam>
</simpleXMLResult>
```

Comment: I think better way of going is to connect to database using oledb and upload data.  You can use powershell to parse the xml and then insert into the database with oledb.

Comment: Thanks for responding! If you mean that I should connect to the vendor who provides the XMLs, that is not an option for me and my company. If I'm misunderstanding, then apologies and clarification welcome.

Comment: If XML is not structured to allow Access to import/link with External Data wizard or with XSLT transform file, will most likely require using text file read/write code and process XML one line at a time. See similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552530/importing-an-xml-file-into-ms-access-with-transform-file. Second requirement is fairly simple - loop through files in a folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057916/how-to-loop-through-a-folder. A question should focus on one issue. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: I mean instead of doing the importing inside Access, add the data to database with a Powershell script.

Comment: Thank you June7 and jdweng! I'll check out the two links and try to educate myself on Powershell. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two XSLT scripts: one to compile all XML files and one to process them to move attribute-centric content to element-centric. To compile all XML, use the `document()` function in XSLT.

**XSLT 1**

- To be run on first XML. Notice `document` starts with second XML.
- Below requires placing *all* in same directory *relative* to first XML with or without subdirectories. If using subdirectories include folders in path inside `document()`. Do not use absolute file paths.
- Use some type of file iteration (VBA loop, PowerShell, Python, etc.) to automate the `document()` lines across the "hundreds" of XML. Run in separate program and copy/paste as needed here or build entire XSLT in code. Remember XSLT is a well-formed XML file!
- If really "hundreds" of XML files, be careful as your master XML may get very large!

```xml
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                             xmlns:doc="http://sdk.prometric.com/schemas/SimpleXMLResults1_4">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"  method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="MasterRoot" namespace="http://sdk.prometric.com/schemas/SimpleXMLResults1_4">
      <xsl:copy-of select="doc:simpleXMLResult"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('Second.xml')/doc:simpleXMLResult/*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('Third.xml')/doc:simpleXMLResult/*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('Fourth.xml')/doc:simpleXMLResult/*"/>
      ...
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XSLT 2**

- To be run on output of above.
- Walks down the needed sections and does not subset specific attributes but traverses all columns. Remove unneeded columns from final tables as  needed.
- See <kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQY72u/3)</kbd> and even import that output in Access to test solution. Your XML was copied under `<MasterRoot>` with a different apptId for second XML: `000000000000000001`.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://sdk.prometric.com/schemas/SimpleXMLResults1_4">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="nmsp">
    <xsl:text>http://sdk.prometric.com/schemas/SimpleXMLResults1_4</xsl:text>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <!-- REMOVE UNNEED ROOT CHILD -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:delivery"/>
  
  <!-- DEMOGAPHICS -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:demographics">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{$nmsp}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:demographic"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="doc:demographic">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}" namespace="{$nmsp}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>  
  
  <!-- SCORES -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:exam">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:score"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:sections"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="doc:score">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="appointmentid" namespace="{$nmsp}">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::doc:simpleXMLResult/doc:demographics/@appointmentid"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::doc:exam/@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{$nmsp}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{$nmsp}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- SECTION -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:sections">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:section"/>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="doc:section">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="appointmentid" namespace="{$nmsp}">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::doc:simpleXMLResult/doc:demographics/@appointmentid"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="examcode" namespace="{$nmsp}">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::doc:exam/@examcode"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{$nmsp}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:itemgroup"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- ITEMS -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:itemgroup">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:item"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="doc:item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="appointmentid" namespace="{$nmsp}">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::doc:simpleXMLResult/doc:demographics/@appointmentid"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="examcode" namespace="{$nmsp}">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::doc:exam/@examcode"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::doc:itemgroup/@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{$nmsp}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{$nmsp}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub TransformAndImportXML()
    ' INCLUDE Microsoft XML, v6.0 REFERENCE
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    ' FIRST TRANSFORMATION
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\First.xml"
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT_1.xsl"
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Master.xml"

    ' SECOND TRANSFORMATION
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Master.xml"
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT_2.xsl"
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\MasterDB.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing

    ' IMPORT INTO DATABASE TO CREATE 4 TABLES: demographics, item, score, section
    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\MasterDB.xml"
    MsgBox "Successfully transformed and imported XML!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

---

**PowerShell**

If VBA's XSLT performance lags due to large Master XML, consider PowerShell using the [.NET XSLT compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=net-5.0). Use its output in Access's `ImportXML`.

```
# FIRST TRANSFORMATION
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.Load("C:\Path\To\XSLT_1.xsl");
$xslt.Transform("C:\Path\To\First.xml", "C:\Path\To\Master.xml");

# SECOND TRANSFORMATION
$xslt.Load("C:\Path\To\XSLT_2.xsl");
$xslt.Transform("C:\Path\To\Master.xml", "C:\Path\To\MasterDB.xml");
```

Comment: Why the lengthy MSXML stuff instead of a single call to `Application.TransformXML`? Do you have any negative experiences with that?

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much Parfait! I'm going to try this now. I'll report back!

Comment: @ErikA, In the past, I found Access' built-in transformer offers limited support compared to MSXML library. More complex XSLT appear to not run as scripted. I am recalling my answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26022541/1422451), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066351/1422451), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40291698/1422451), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67576906/1422451) showing both options.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't encountered that before but I haven't done any complex XSLT so I trust you're right it can occur. Thanks for telling, might save me from asking a question if I encounter oddities with it in the future.